# What happens when I grab an object from a static ArrayList and change its parameters?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, static

I have a static `ArrayList<Profile>` that I want to be able to access from any activity within my app. When I do finally get around to it, I do something like this:

```
Profile profile = Globals.profiles.get(selected);
```

Normally I understand that when I retrieve and object from an `ArrayList` and make changes to it, I am changing the object in the `ArrayList`. This is the behavior I want but I wonder if it still holds true if the `ArrayList` is static. For instance, if I:

```
profile.setNewName("Mike");
```

Is the name changed only for the local object derived from the static `ArrayList`, or is the object in the `ArrayList` updated as well? Like I said, this is expected behavior when `ArrayList` is not static.

Comment: did you check in java references what "static" means  ?

Comment: As far as I know, it means only one instance of `ArrayList` exists for any `Global` objects created. I think in C++ though, these objects are also stored in a different part of memory (I'm not sure if this is the case for Java) than locally defined objects, so I'm hesitant here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*static* means, that  the member is associated to the class and not to a concrete instance of the class. 
In your case it means, the ArrayList is member of your Globals class.

To answer your question: Since you are working on the Object-References, you are directly updating the Object in your (static) ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the same behavior as if you updated a non static instance of an ArrayList

I think you need to research what static means in Java